# How to process data in parallel but write results in a single file in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark job that:

- Reads data from hdfs
- Does some intensive transformation **without shuffling and aggregation (only map operations)**
- Writes results back to hdfs

Let's say I have 10GB of raw data (40 blocks = 40 input partitions), which results in 100MB of processed data. To avoid generating many small files in hdfs I use "coalesce(1)" statement in order to write single file with results.
Doing so I get only 1 task running (because of "coalesce(1)" and absence of shuffling), which processes all 10GB in a single thread.

**Is there a way to do actual intensive processing in 40 parallel tasks and reduce number of partitions right before writing to disk and avoid data shuffle?**

I have an idea that might work - to cache dataframe in memory after all processing (do a count to force Spark to cache the data) and then put "coalesce(1)" and write dataframe to disk

Answer (score 2):

The documentation clearly warns about this behavior and provides the solution:

> However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this, you can call repartition. This will add a shuffle step, but means the current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever the current partitioning is).

So instead

```
coalesce(1)
```

you can try

```
repartition(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! it indeed does make sense :)